# Get and Set ContextMenuStrip Items

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, menuitem

I have a ContextMenuStrip declared in a custom control, and i cant seem to find a way for the control to return or set the ContextMenuStrip's items collection.
I tried this code but it doesn't work

```
class Class1 : Panel
{
    ContextMenuStrip _Menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
    public ToolStripItemCollection Items
    {
        get { return _Menu.Items; }
        set { _Menu.Items.AddRange(value); }
    }
}
```

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exam this :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ContextMenuStrip cms = new ContextMenuStrip();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //cms.Items[;
    }
    public ToolStripItemCollection ConItems
    {
        get
        {
            return cms.Items;
        }
        set
        {
            cms.Items.Clear();
            ToolStripItemCollection tsc=(ToolStripItemCollection)value;
            foreach (ToolStripItem tsi in tsc)
            {
                cms.Items.Add(tsi);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set  
ContextMenuStrip menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
menu.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Item1", aNiceImage, someFunction));
menu.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Item2", alsoNiceImage, someOtherFunction));

//Get
private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) 
{
   contextMenuStrip1.Items[3].Select();
}
```

Comment: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip(v=vs.80).aspx)
See This Link if the above code doesnot helps you in any way

Comment: That's not what i want. I want a property inside the custom control that returns and sets the ContextMenuStrip's item collection.

Comment: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx]
it will help you for sure